# Fbx import bones outside of body!

Tags: bones, .fbx

I exported and fbx from unreal engine 5, I then used auto desk fbx converter to convert the fbx file following a tut on youtube where it works flawlessly.
I then imported the fbx into blender as in the tutorial. However the skeletal bones are outside and infront of the body about 2-3 inches onscreen turned at around 30 degrees horizontal.
I've tried not converting the fbx and still the same problem.
I'm a blender newbie so any help appreciated.